# update textfile delimiter java

Tags: java, file, file-io, text-files

I am just starting to learn java and I found an example on how to update a textfile but I need some guidance on how I can manipulate it to update elements in my textfile with delimiters. for example if i wish to edit my address2 with a new address

> login,name,address,contact
>
> login1,name1,address1,contact1
>
> login2,name2,address2,contact2

```
File f=new File("appendOldFile.txt");

        FileInputStream fs = null;
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String textinLine;

        try {
             fs = new FileInputStream(f);
             in = new InputStreamReader(fs);
             br = new BufferedReader(in);

            while(true)
            {
                textinLine=br.readLine();
                if(textinLine==null)
                    break;
                sb.append(textinLine);
            }
              String textToEdit1 = "abc";
              int cnt1 = sb.indexOf(textToEdit1);
              sb.replace(cnt1,cnt1+textToEdit1.length(),"New Append text");

              String textToEdit2 = "xyz";
              int cnt2 = sb.indexOf(textToEdit2);
              sb.replace(cnt2,cnt2+textToEdit2.length(),"Second new edit text");

              fs.close();
              in.close();
              br.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: so what is the error you are getting

Comment: no error. but can u give me guidance on which part i should modify to update my delimited textfile?

Comment: See [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

Comment: *"which part i should modify"*  Modify the code.  Too broad for SO, voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must have to iterate through your file using and find the required login as a key to change the corresponding address with for this I'm giving you just hints use google or futher search by yourself in order for the top best results.
for further assistance reply...

```
    File f=new File("C:/Users/Junaid Hassan/Contacts",FINAL1);

    FileReader fr=new FileReader(f); 
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    String key;
    while((key=br.readLine())!=null)    //then you have to split the strings 

    String SPLIT[]=NAME.split(",");
            String Login=SPLIT[0];
                String Name=SPLIT[1];
                    String Address=SPLIT[2];
                        String Contact=SPLIT[3];
//then put a check that if your login will match a key
if(Login.equals(key)){
   //here do what you want change the address
}
   }
```

Comment: If you find it useful you must mark the answe as useful please

Answer (score 1):

In general, you do not modify existing text file. You load it, modify the text, then rewrite it. This is because text files do not have fixed-size records (lines, whatever), so any change generally involves everything after the changed location shifting by inserted/removed amount of text. File systems in general do not support inserting/removing in the middle of file. Thus, text files aren't modified as files, they're rewritten when changes are done.

You have two basic ways to go about this in a program. You can load the text file as one text string, or more likely a list of strings, one string for each line in text file. Then you can modify these strings, and write them back. *This is what I recommend as your first step*: read lines in file int a `ArrayList<String>`, then manipulate that list, then write strings to a file when you want to save changes.

Alternatively, you can actually parse the text file data, so you would have Java objects with fields like `address`, `name`, etc. And then you modify this data as data in you program, and then you basically create a new file from this data.

If you have clear 1:1 relationship between text file contents and objects in your program, for example each line becomes one object with all data coming from that line, and then when written, all data of the object is written as single line, then this is called "serialization": converting objects to and from a chunk of bytes (which does not have to be human-readable text, but can be), suitable for saving to file or transferring over network connection. However, in this case you can probably forget about "serialization", as it is a fairly advanced concept, and get back to it after you've learned more Java.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. im currently looking at arraylist now.